# How to determine custom server evaluation in EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, ef-core-3.1

I have this entity

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Id{get; private set;}
   public DateTime CreatedOn {get; private set;}
   public bool IsActive {get; private set;}
   public bool CanBeDisplayed => IsActive  && CreatedOn > DateTime.Now.AddYear(-1);
}
```

I want to this `dbcontext.Foos.Where(f=>f.CanBeDisplayed).ToArray();` could be evaluated on the sql server side. May there is an attribute or some binding in the DBContext class who can give me a work arround. 
My goal is to have a Rich Model, ef core compatible, am I missing something?

Comment: See Generated Values : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible workarounds:

1. Introducing [Computed Column](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascomputedcolumnsql-method) and providing sql for it.
2. Making expression tree

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; private set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; private set; }
    // mark ignored for EF?
    public bool CanBeDisplayed => _compiled(this);

    private static Func<Foo, bool> _compiled = CanBeDisplayedExp.Compile();
    public static Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> CanBeDisplayedExp = f => f.IsActive && f.CreatedOn > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
}
```

With usage limited to `dbcontext.Foos.Where(Foo.CanBeDisplayedExp).ToArray()`

Also not sure that EF can translate `DateTime.Now.AddYears`.

P.S.

Just FYI `Linq2Db` has [expression based calculated colums](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/releasenotes/2.0.0.html#calculated-columns) and [Expression Methods](http://blog.linq2db.com/2016/06/how-to-teach-linq-to-db-convert-custom.html#ExpressionMethod) support.